# Apply CSS/SASS rule to outer elements and not to inner elements

Tags: css, sass

I'm currently working with a third party JS library that inserts content areas within the page/DOM, the library is Sir Trevor.

Now I wish to apply some custom CSS rules, for example:

```
.st-block:before {
    @include roundedIcon(38px, $colorX, $colorY);
    content: counter(mylistCounter, decimal);
    counter-increment: mylistCounter;
    margin-right: $margin-variable;
}
```

now this works great and a number is put before my divs with the `.st-block` class. However a DIV with this class can and some times does contain a child div with the same class, like so:

```
<div class="content">

    <div id="st-block-16" class="st-block st-icon--add st-item-ready" data-type="listicle" data-instance="st-editor-8">
        <!-- here's the child... grrr!!! -->
        <div id="st-block-17" class="st-block st-icon--add st-item-ready" data-type="listicle" data-instance="st-editor-8">
            Child Div Here...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="st-block-18" class="st-block st-icon--add st-item-ready" data-type="listicle" data-instance="st-editor-8">
    No Child Div
    </div>

    <div id="st-block-19" class="st-block st-icon--add st-item-ready" data-type="listicle" data-instance="st-editor-8">
    No Child Div
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I amend my CSS/SASS class to prevent the child/nested div with the same class being affected (in the example above the one with ID `id="st-block-17"`)? PLEASE NOTE that I have no control over the alocation of IDs

Answer (score 0):

Select only the classes which are only one level deeper then the div with class="content"

```
.content > .st-block
```